# Habilitar el jbutton siempre y cuando el jtable no este vacio. JAVA

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2

Parece ser sencillo, pero esto ya me esta llevando 2 dias. Simplemente tengo un jTable y tres botones. Agregar, Modificar y Eliminar. Los datos se agregan, modifican y eliminan perfecto. En el constructor del JFrame donde tengo estos componentes, los botones Modificar y Eliminar los dejo inactivos (SetEnabled(false)) por logica razon de que siempre en la primera instancia el jtable estara vacio y por ese motivo los dejo en ese estado, salvo el de Agregar.

Pero aqui va el problema, al agregar datos al jtable quiero que se me habiliten los mismos que los deje inactivos.

Probe de la forma condicional JTable.GetRowCount, si era 0 que siga inactivos, sino, habilitarlos. Probe recorriendo el jtable con un for por columnas y filas (JTable.GetRowCount, Jtable.GetColumnCount) y dentro del mismo dar una condicion Jtable.GetValueAt(fila,columna) == null; pero tambien no cambia sus estados.

Se que estan los eventos del key (keyReleased) o mouse (mouseClicked o mousePressed) pero estos no lo puedo usar, puesto que en ningun momento cargo datos dentro del mismo jtable, lo que hago es cargar mediante unos jtextfields y con el boton agregar se va guardando en la tabla. Con el mouse tampoco es el caso porque no depende de que el boton Agregar(el unico caso) al darle click se me habiliten, en todo caso si el jtable esta vacio los botones no se van a desactivar.

Ahora estoy probando con los eventos del jtable, que mas bien seria el caso, pero no puedo conseguir el oyente correcto que haría lo que quiero que ocurra.

En fin, creo que he sido bastante especifico para esto y veo que no es relevante que muestre el codigo. En todo caso si lo requieren lo subo.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de esto, estaré eternamente agradecido con cada aporte de ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar esta validación
Recuerda que un Jtable siempre tiene un DefaultTableModel por lo tanto siempre puedes acceder a la misma para conocer la data que se despliega en la tabla, por lo tanto aquí te dejo este código

```
boton.setEnabled(tabla.getModel().getRowCount() > 0 ? true : false);
```

Comment: Hola AndyC, antes que nada muchas gracias por tu ayuda!. Te comento el resultado que se dio. En parte se soluciona el problema. Al ejecutarlo la primera vez lo desactiva y se activa bien los botones!. Pero al eliminar todos los datos se queda activo los botones, no se desactivan. Estoy viendo si puedo aportar en algo. Si tenes la solucion, Por favor te agredeceria mucho por tu ayuda! Saludos

Comment: Disculpa AndyC tuve un pequeño error, tenia para habilitar los botones que tenia desactivados en el boton agregar. Entonces cuando daba click se activan los mismos. Ahora los saque y lamentablemente no se arreglo el problema directamente. Disculpa las confusiones.